# Alert controller with dropdown menu and keyboard option? Swift 3, Xcode 8, IOS

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, swift3, uialertcontroller

I'm a huge beginner when it comes to programming.

I currently have an alert controller set up so that when I click a button in the view controller [an alert controller pops up](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png). I can enter text into a textfield (in the alert controller) and the text will show up on a label (in my view controller), when I click okay (in the alert controller). This is the code for what i have:

```
//Text button

@IBOutlet weak var TextLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func TextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
print("Text Button Tapped")
openTextAlert()
}

func openTextAlert() {
//Create Alert Controller
let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Whatever Text Your Heart Desires:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

//Create Cancel Action
let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

alert9.addAction(cancel9)

//Create OK Action
let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
    let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
    print(textfield?.text!)
    self.TextLabel.text = textfield?.text!
}

alert9.addAction(ok9)

//Add Text Field
alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
    textfield.placeholder = "Whatever text you want to enter"
}

//Present Alert Controller
self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I get multiple actions in my alert controller so that it ALSO acts as [a dropdown menu with certain words so that I don't need to always write out key words?](http://nshipster.s3.amazonaws.com/uialertcontroller-alert-one-two-three-cancel.png) I need both, the ability to type my own words and phrases and a preset of words and phrases for efficiency.

Please help! I'm a huge noob. Thank you :)
Swift 3, Xcode 8, IOS

Comment: I found the solution in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423698/how-to-scroll-through-actions-in-alert-controller-xcode-8-swift-3-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write this using your code. Is this what you need?

EDIT: the yourNewButtonTapped function is simply to show you how you can set a condition to show either the simple alert or the actionSheet. In this function, when you click your new button, and then your TextButton, your alert will be shown. If you click your new button again, you will set userWantsToShowAlert as false. And when you click again your textButtonTapped, the openActionSheet will be called.

You can do this in so many ways.

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextLabel: UILabel!

var userWantsToShowAlert = false

@IBAction func yourNewButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        userWantsToShowAlert = !userWantsToShowAlert 
        print("User wants to show alert? \(userWantsToShowAlert)")
//This is userWantsToShowAlert is false, it will change it to true. And if it is true, it will change it to false.
    }

@IBAction func TextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Text Button Tapped")
        if(userWantsToShowAlert){
            openTextAlert()
        }else{
            openActionSheetAlert()
        }


    }

    func openTextAlert() {
        //Create Alert Controller
        let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Whatever Text Your Heart Desires:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        //Create Cancel Action
        let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

        alert9.addAction(cancel9)

        //Create OK Action
        let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
            let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
            print(textfield?.text!)
            self.TextLabel.text = textfield?.text!
        }

        alert9.addAction(ok9)

        //Add Text Field
        alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
            textfield.placeholder = "Whatever text you want to enter"
        }

        //Present Alert Controller
        self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }

    func openActionSheetAlert(){
        let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Whatever Text Your Heart Desires:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        //Create Cancel Action
        let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alert9.addAction(cancel9)


         let bt1 = UIAlertAction(title: "1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 1"}

    alert9.addAction(bt1)

    let bt2 = UIAlertAction(title: "2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 2"}

    alert9.addAction(bt2)


    let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 3"}

    alert9.addAction(bt3)

    let bt4 = UIAlertAction(title: "4", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.TextLabel.text = "Word 4"}
    alert9.addAction(bt4)

alert9.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            alert9.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
            self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: Thank You! :)  I get an error for the "something" part of:
   
     if(/*something*/){


What should i write in there?

Comment: @DanielG that /*something*/ is the condition you want to check in order to choose showing either the Alert or the ActionSheet.

Comment: Im unfamiliar with how I should proceed as I'm very new. What should I write in for my condition?

Comment: let say you have a var userWantsToShowAlert = false. Si, you ask if(userWantsToShowAlert(){  openTextAlert() }else{ openActionSheetAlert() }

Comment: okay but how would i work that variable into a workable option that i can click?

Comment: set var userWantsToShowAlert = false as a global variable (Just below your UIViewController definition). You can add another button to set that variable true or false ( @IBAction func yourButton(_ sender: UIButton) { userWantsToShowAlert = !userWantsToShowAlert } ).

Comment: Dude, I have no idea. Can you please edit your comment?

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Comment: @DanielG Check now. If you didnt understand it or if it's not what you're asking, open a chat and I will help you as much as I can

Comment: @DanielG In order to not make this post more robust, please write in http://pastebin.com/ the complete error message you got and send me the link

Comment: @DanielG Edited. Did you tried that on an iPad? That's a common error while presenting ActionSheets on iPad

Comment: Yes, if i click the new button first, then click my old button it calls my text box. Any other order of operations and it will crash. Is there a way to show multiple actions in my text box? like 'OK' 'Cancel' 'Special Word 1' 'Special Word 2' etc?

Comment: Replace the code with the edited one. I just added this in openActionSheetAlert:
alert9.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            alert9.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
Before:
            self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)

Comment: YES! It worked!! :) Thank you, now all I need is for my action sheet to produce the words I select into my label

Comment: @DanielG I'm glad! Just for your information, that error you got only happens in iPad. But with that fix you shouldn't get any problem.

Comment: Much appreciated. Any idea on how il get my action sheet to work with the label?

Comment: You can show either alert or actionSheet, but not both combined. But you can recreate it. The most actionSheet-like elements you can use are UIStackView (https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views). They help you to use multiple buttons with the same size.

Comment: Thats a good idea, although all i need to do is to click a button in my action sheet so that a word goes into my label. Right now all I have is an action sheet that has buttons that do nothing to my label.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot modify the default actionSheet. You can use a third-party library like https://github.com/yabuzaki/YBAlertController or https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Comment: Thank you. not sure why you did not have any up votes with so many approvals from users.